# Liferay export web content with images to doc format

Tags: export, liferay, libreoffice

I am having problem with Liferay Portal Community Edition 6.2 CE GA2. I have tried to export web content whitch contained image with OpenOffice but images are not visible in exported .doc file, only text.

Can anybody help, please?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Images gets stored in Document And Media, you may have to export those images as well

Comment: I figured out, that images are exported but have minimum size (in document they looks like 1x1 pixel... although in web content there are correct size definitions (width=40 height=40)...)